# Is there a way to bring FALSE values to the top of the column?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I've been comparing between two CSV files and managed to do it using the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;'file.csv'!$A$2:$AD$9890;1;FALSE)
```

I am comparing only the first column in each worksheet, so I get a resulting column that tells me which values are new (the difference between the two sheets). The column has some `#N/A` values. Now, is there a way to bring these `#N/A` values to the top?

Example:

```
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
77851
7452
6524
10522
4522
```

Comment: Do you want to Sort the result column? Or do you want to sort the source column such that the values which result in N/A appear at the top? Or something else entirely?  It's not clear what you're asking. Consider adding more detail, including example of input & output, as well as detail about what you have tried so far (this is known as [MCVE] and is part of [Ask] a good question).

Comment: @I want to have N/A in the resulting column at the top. I will try to edit my question a bit.

Comment: The only way to achieve this would be sorting/filtering the results. Do it manually or create a macro are your only choices available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use autofilter to achieve that.

Assume I have the following data, where I have the lookup value `=VLOOKUP(B2;$H$3:$I$6;2;0)` in cell `E2`

[image]

I would put a filter on my headers (row 1) and create  dummy column (Column A) with values 1 and upward.

[image]

When you filter the lookup column "Sort Largest to Smallest" the #N/A values will be all on the top.

[image]

The dummy row is only to "restore" your data as it was from the beginning. Not necessary for the filter, but could be nice to have.

[image]